# How to pass arguments to keywords from testcase using robotframework?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

i want to pass the arguments from testcase to keyword.

what i am trying to do?
i have the testcase with arguments like below

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test something happens
    Login
    ${val2} =  somevalue1
    ${val2} =  somevalue2
    ${name} =  somename
    Draw something  ${name}  ${val1}  ${val2}

*******keywords************
Draw something 
    Input Text    ${name_input}    ${name}
    Input Text    ${name_input}    ${val1} 
    Input Text    ${name_input}    ${val2}
```

How can i pass the arguments from testcase to keyword Draw something
i was trying to pass it directly to keyword like below

*********keywords*******
    Draw something     ${name}  ${val1} ${val2}

but gives error keyword expected 0 arguments but got 3

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: This is clearly documented in the user guide. Why do you need our help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation on how to use arguments with Robot Framework keywords:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-arguments

And here is an example printing out a full name based on arguments `first` and `last`:

```
*** Keywords ***
Print Name
    [Arguments]       ${FIRST}  ${LAST}
    Log To Console  ${FIRST} ${LAST}

*** Test Cases ***
Test printing a name
    Print Name  John  Doe
```

As you can see, you need to add the `[Arguments]` section under your keyword:

```
*** Keywords ***
Draw something
    [Arguments]   ${name}  ${val1}  ${val2}
    Input Text    ${name_input}    ${name}
    Input Text    ${name_input}    ${val1} 
    Input Text    ${name_input}    ${val2}
```

Comment: thanks is there a way that i pass the arguments augmented to the keyword itsef.

Comment: There is, its called embedding arguments to keywords: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-names In this case you need to implement the keyword in a python code file.